# Create Dynamic Component in specific location of template reference

Tags: angular

Is there a way to get the specific template reference and then create the component base on the click event.

What I wanted is that when the button is click the dynamic component should be created based on the location of the template reference `folderContainer` where the button is clicked.

My current issue is that the component is always created in the first generated `div` of the template reference.

**app.component.ts**

```js
import {
  Component, ViewContainerRef,
  ViewChild,
  ComponentFactoryResolver
} from '@angular/core';

import { FolderComponent } from './folder/folder.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  folders = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3'];

  @ViewChild('folderContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) folderContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  createFolder(event) {
    console.log(event)
    const folderFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(FolderComponent);
    const folder = this.folderContainer.createComponent(folderFactory);
    console.log(folder)
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let folder of folders">
  <p>{{folder}}</p>
  <button (click)="createFolder($event)">ADD</button>
  <div #folderContainer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the [stackblitz link.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-component-specific-reference?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild`. Using `ViewChildren` you will get the array of references for all the `templates` in a loop.

```
@ViewChildren('folderContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) foldersContainer: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  createFolder(event, index) {
    const containers = this.foldersContainer.toArray()
    const folderFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(FolderComponent);
    const folder = containers[index].createComponent(folderFactory);
  }
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let folder of folders; let i=index">
  <p>{{folder}}</p>
  <button (click)="createFolder($event, i)">ADD</button>
  <div #folderContainer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-component-specific-reference-3serct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I see using ViewChild we will not be able to get the array of our templates instead it will look for the first element of the template?

Comment: Yes, that is what was happening because all the elements have the same reference. `ViewChildren` is the solution